# Magento 2: How to add shortcode js to block

Tags: magento2

I have a shortcode with  one widget reviews in .js

I need to add this code to block in panel admin and then display in the frontend via widget.

When I paste this .js code directly to block Magento 2 then after saving automatic disappear this code.

How can I add the .js widget and then call in the block, and next via the widget to the frontend?

update:
Im not sure I correct do it:
I created `.phtml` file in:

```
app/code/TrustMate/Opinions/view/frontend/templates/trustmatewidget.phtml
```

Now I try call in block:

```
<p>{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="TrustMate_Opinions::templates/trustmatewidget.phtml"}}</p>
```

But currently not result. I correct do path to this script?

Comment: you added code in phtml? and have you cleared cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call phtml file from block and in your phtml file add your widget's short code

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::myfiles/myfile.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Rejesh can you please check my update